# Visual Studio 2019 Remotely Debug GDB on Non-POSIX ARM Device

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, arm, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and am attempting to set up a development environment that allows me to cross-compile for ARM11 on WSL, deploy it to my device, and attach Visual Studio's debugger to a custom gdb server that runs on the device. Most of the mentions of remotely debugging with GDB using Visual Studio mentions use of SSHing into the machine first. The device I am attempting to debug remotely on is not POSIX and does not have a shell to SSH into, just a built in GDB server on port 4000.

I know it works, because using WSL, the following works:

```
$ gdb-multiarch application.elf
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
<GNU Licensing crap>
Reading symbols from application.elf...done.
(gdb) target remote 192.168.43.121:4000
Remote debugging using 192.168.43.121:4000
warning: Target description specified unknown osabi "3DS"
svcWaitSynchronization () at /home/fincs/pacman-packages/libctru/src/libctru-2.0.0/libctru/source/svc.s:263
263     /home/fincs/pacman-packages/libctru/src/libctru-2.0.0/libctru/source/svc.s: No such file or directory.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Start calloc test... micros elapsed: 1.592000 <-- from device's stderr
```

Knowing that this works perfectly fine, I wanted to try to work this intro Visual Studio because I really like the IDE's debugging capabilities. Based on their description of VS's capability to interface with GDB, I figured it should be possible to hook into the debug server on my 2DS. However, all I have been able to figure out and try is to add a no-auth connection in Visual Studio's connection manager and maybe I can work it into the debug task from there, but this is what happens when I try:

[image: Debugger connection attempt with error message]

So I stop here. I'm not sure what else to try. I also don't imagine that this is the final barrier, because two other things don't really match up with the `gdb-multiarch` process that I get working through WSL, namely that:

1. I don't see any way to specify to Visual Studio what symbol file to use like I do for GDB (`application.elf`). I suppose perhaps it will have those anyway due to being an IDE.
2. Since I am debugging from an x86 machine, I am not sure if Visual Studio will be able to make sense of the ARM11 gdb server. This is why I use `gdb-multiarch` when doing it through WSL. Using the defuault gdb doesn't yield results.

How can I move forward to allow Visual Studio to play nicely with this no-auth ARM11 gdb server?